# Why does this AVR code for ATMega128 behave the way it does?

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, atmega

I have the following code for ATMega128:

Some libraries and functions are not used as I haven't completed the code completely because I am stuck at this problem for days now.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define F_CPU       8000000UL
#define BAUDRATE    9600
#define UBRR_VALUE  ((F_CPU)/(16UL*BAUDRATE))-1 //For UBRR registers

#define MASTER_WATCHDOG_MENU    "\rEnter MS WD Choice (& period):\rA-30ms\rB-250ms\rC-500ms\rYour input:\0"
#define SLAVE_WATCHDOG_MENU     "\rEnter SLV WD Choice (& period):\rA-0.5s\rB-1.0s\rC-2.0s\rYour input:\0"
#define USER_MENU               "\rEnter choice (and period): 1-Mem Dump 2-Last Entry 3-Restart\rYour input:\0"

void ConfigureXMEMMode(void){
    MCUCR |= (1 << SRE); 
    XMCRA = 0;           
    XMCRB = (1 << XMM2) | (0 << XMM1) | (1 << XMM0);
}

void ConfigureUSARTInterfaces(void){

    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(UBRR_VALUE >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)(UBRR_VALUE);
    
    UBRR1H = (unsigned char)(UBRR_VALUE >> 8);
    UBRR1L = (unsigned char)(UBRR_VALUE);
    
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<RXCIE0) | (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<TXCIE0); 
    UCSR1B = (1<<RXEN1) | (1<<RXCIE1) | (1<<TXEN1) | (1<<TXCIE1);
    
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
    UCSR1C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

void USART0_TransmitByte(unsigned char byteToTransmit){
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0))); 
    UDR0 = byteToTransmit;
}

void USART0_TransmitString(unsigned char *stringToTransmit){
    unsigned char i = 0;
    for(i = 0; stringToTransmit[i] != '\0'; i++){
        USART0_TransmitByte(stringToTransmit[i]);
    }
}

void USART1_TransmitByte(unsigned char byteToTransmit){
    while(!(UCSR1A & (1<<UDRE1)));
    UDR1 = byteToTransmit;
}

void USART1_TransmitString(unsigned char *stringToTransmit){
    unsigned char i = 0;
    for(i = 0; stringToTransmit[i] != '\0'; i++){
        USART1_TransmitByte(stringToTransmit[i]);
    }
}

unsigned char USART0_ReceiveByte(void){
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0))); 
    return UDR0; 
}

unsigned char USART1_ReceiveByte(void){
    while(!(UCSR1A & (1<<RXC1)));
    return UDR1;
}

void ConfigureWatchdogTimer(void){
    while(EECR & (1 << EEWE)); 
    EEARH = 0x00; 
    EEARL = 0x00; 
    EECR  = 1 << EERE; 

    if(EEDR == 0xFF){
        EEARL = 0x01;
        if(EEDR == 0xFF){
            EECR = 0 << EERE;
            ConfigureMasterWD();
        }
    }
    
    while(EECR & (1 << EEWE));
    EEARH = 0x00;
    EEARL = 0x02;
    EECR  = 1 << EERE;
    
    if(EEDR == 0xFF){
        EEARL = 0x03;
        if (EEDR == 0xFF){
            EECR = 0 << EERE;
            ConfigureSlaveWD();
        }
    }
}

void ConfigureMasterWD(){
    USART0_TransmitString(MASTER_WATCHDOG_MENU);
    
    unsigned char userInput = USART0_ReceiveByte();
    switch(userInput){
        case 'A': case 'a':
            WDTCR = (1 << WDE) | (0 << WDP2) | (0 << WDP1) | (1 << WDP0); //30ms
            break;
        case 'B': case 'b':
            WDTCR = (1 << WDE) | (1 << WDP2) | (0 << WDP1) | (0 << WDP0); //250ms
            break;
        case 'C': case 'c':
            WDTCR = (1 << WDE) | (1 << WDP2) | (0 << WDP1) | (1 << WDP0); //500ms
            break;
    }
    USART0_TransmitString("\rDone!\r");
}

void ConfigureSlaveWD(){
    USART0_TransmitString(SLAVE_WATCHDOG_MENU);
    
    unsigned char userInput = USART0_ReceiveByte();
    switch(userInput){
        case 'A': case 'a':
            WDTCR = (1 << WDE) | (1 << WDP2) | (0 << WDP1) | (1 << WDP0); //500ms
            break;
        case 'B': case 'b':
            WDTCR = (1 << WDE) | (1 << WDP2) | (1 << WDP1) | (0 << WDP0); //1.0s
            break;
        case 'C': case 'c':
            WDTCR = (1 << WDE) | (1 << WDP2) | (1 << WDP1) | (1 << WDP0); //2.0s
            break;
    }
    USART0_TransmitString("\rDone!\r");
}


void Sleep(){
    sei();
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_IDLE);
    sleep_enable();
    sleep_cpu();
}

void WakeUp(){
    sleep_disable();
    cli();
}

int main(void){
    ConfigureXMEMMode();
    ConfigureUSARTInterfaces();
    ConfigureWatchdogTimer();

    USART0_TransmitString("ATMEGA128 TO USART0");
    USART1_TransmitString("ATMEGA128 TO USART1");
    
    Sleep();
    while(1);
}

ISR(USART0_RX_vect){
    WakeUp();
    new_user_read_char = UDR0;
    USART1_TransmitByte(UDR0);
    Sleep();
}
```

When simulate this code on Proteus, I see that the whole main function is in an infinite loop as the virtual terminal continuously repeats the ConfigureWatchdogTimer() function. However, the behavior that I expect is, configuration functions only run once, the CPU goes to sleep mode and only wakes up when an interrupt happens, which for this code is receiving a byte on usart0. What am I missing here or what is it that I am not understanding?
The interrupt that I wrote somewhat works as if I constantly spam a character, that character does show up in the other terminal every once in a while.

Behavior that I get on Proteus when I run this code on ATMega128
[image: Behavior that I get on Proteus when I run this code on ATMega128]

Comment: I don't know anything about this system, but a watchdog timer is normally used to reset the CPU if it is not "kicked" or reset periodically. I don't see anything in your code that would reset the timer. What do you expect to happen (after you configure the watchdog)? Why are you even using a watchdog timer here? That it just resets and your code starts again looks like expected behaviour to me.

Comment: I am working on an assignment and watchdog timers were a part of it. Though I coded the configuration part of it, I didn't put it into use like you said. So the problem is caused by the incorrect use of watchdog timer?

Comment: Well, as I said, a watchdog timer, once started, will reset your CPU unless you reset the timer periodically. So you need to either make sure you reset it in a timely manner, or don't start it at all. I don't know what your goal is, so I don't think I can say much more.

Comment: Watchdogs in the most basic mode are easy: initialize it, then write a certain sequence to a register before it times out ("feeding" or "kicking" the watchdog). In correctly designed programs, this "feeding" is ideally done at the top of the for-ever loop in main().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Occasional code restart is a usual sign of some missed interrupt handler.

For example, you have receive (RXCIEn) and transmission (TXCIEn) interrupts enabled for both USARTs in `ConfigureUSARTInterfaces`:

```
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<RXCIE0) | (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<TXCIE0); 
    UCSR1B = (1<<RXEN1) | (1<<RXCIE1) | (1<<TXEN1) | (1<<TXCIE1);
```

but have only handler for `USART0_RX_vect`.

Either define ISRs for other USARTs interrupts, or disable (do not set) corresponding `TXCIE`/`RXCIE`-bits in USART configurations

Comment: This is it! I added all the handlers like you said and it works now. I guess I should have been just a bit more patient and have written all the handlers before testing. Thank you!

Comment: While this is correct answer to implicit question "why is my code restarting?", it does not cover the whole story "what is wrong with the code?". Preventing unhandled interrupts to reset the MCU solves first immediate issue, but whole usage of sleep_cpu() and ISRs is still completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is conceptually wrong. It can look like it is working properly, but it is not.

If your code generates no other interrupts than USART0_RX, it will eventually crash with stack overflow, because you are never returning from ISR but nesting them. If there are other interrupt sources with empty handler occurring often enough (like your TX interrupt), it will accidentally (=it is not how you are supposed to do it, but only a side-effect) prevent the interrupt nesting with related stack overflow, but your MCU won't be sleeping, it will busy-loop on last while(1) in the main() instead.

What is wrong:

1. The sleep should go into main loop, not before it. That is, end of your main() function should look approximately like: while (1) {do_handle_all events(); prepare_sleep(); sleep_cpu(); disable_sleep();} so after an interrupt occurring and ISR being run the main loop wakes up, handles any event related to the interrupt and goes to sleep again.
2. Except if you know EXACTLY what are you doing (and no, you do not, sorry) you shall never use sleep_cpu() and neither sei()/cli() in the ISR. Full stop. Let the ISR finish ASAP and call sleep_cpu() from the main loop.
3. Generally any long blocking code in ISR has potential to cause hard to debug issues. Again, if you do not know what and why are you doing, stick to rule of thumb that ISR has run and finish in shortest possible time. It handles whatever hardware needs immediate(!) response and sets a flag (semaphore) for main loop to handle "slow" rest of processing.

Regarding the use of sleep_cpu(). Note that code flow will not continue from SLEEP instruction after wake up. It goes first into respective ISR (depending on event which woke up the MCU) and only when ISR is completed, code jumps back after the SLEEP instruction.